# Can't Specify Runtime Version in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I thought this would be straightforward but so far it isn't. I'm trying to specify the runtime version in a buildspec (using CDK in python).  In the below snippet, if I specify the `nodejs` version without quotes then python complains that `nodejs` is an undefined variable. If I put it in quotes then it doesn't update the runtime version.

How do I specify the version?

```
        codebuild.Project(
            self,
            "client-frontend-react-codebuild",
            project_name="frontend-react",
            build_spec=codebuild.BuildSpec.from_object(

                {
                    "version": "0.2",
                    "phases": {
                        "install": {
                            "runtime-versions": {nodejs: "16.x"}
                        },  # this doesn't work
                        "build": {
                            "commands": [
                                "echo Hello, World!",
                            ]
                        },
                    },
                }
)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cdk diff` after adding `"runtime-versions": {"nodejs": "16.x"}`

Comment: @gshpychka That's not going to produce a meaningful output because I can't deploy the stack without quotes (i.e. `"runtime-versions": {nodejs: "16.x"}`.

Comment: I don't understand - you need to deploy it *with* quotes, otherwise it wouldn't be valid Python.

Comment: If I remove the quotes and run `cdk synth` I get the following error: `NameError: name 'nodejs' is not defined`

Comment: Yeah - *don't* remove quotes. The quotes are needed, otherwise it wouldn't be valid Python.

Comment: Right, so when I run it with quotes the version of node is not correct.  Specifically, inside the codebuild, if I run `node --version` then I get `v10.19.0` as the output.  This isn't a huge issue because I can update node via `n lts`, but that's not the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I understood. Refer to my first comment: "Please add the output of cdk diff after adding `"runtime-versions": {"nodejs": "16.x"}`"

Comment: It would also be useful to know which image you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default, the build image used in the project is `aws/codebuild/standard:1.0`, which doesn't support `runtime-versions`.

From the [docs on runtime-versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.phases.install.runtime-versions):

> A runtime version is supported with the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later and the Amazon Linux 2 standard image 1.0 or later.

From the [docs on the `Project` construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.Project.html#environment), specifically the `environment` prop:

> default: BuildEnvironment.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_1_0

To enable support for `runtime-versions`, specify a build image that supports it. For example, here's Standard 6.0, which is Ubuntu 22.04:

```py
codebuild.Project(
    self,
    "client-frontend-react-codebuild",
    project_name="frontend-react",
    build_spec=codebuild.BuildSpec.from_object(
    {
        "version": "0.2",
        "phases": {
            "install": {
                "runtime-versions": {"nodejs": "16.x"}
            },  # this doesn't work
            "build": {
                "commands": [
                    "echo Hello, World!",
                ]
            },
        },
    }
    ),
    environment=codebuild.BuildEnvironment(
        build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_6_0
    )
)
```

Comment: That worked (mostly), thanks for your help. I had to change the environment to the following: `environment=codebuild.BuildEnvironment(build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_6_0)`. If you can update the answer I'll accept it.  Thanks again, I wouldn't have found that solution for quite some time.

Comment: Ah, you're right, updated the answer.